# Comic or manga that involves princess things

Tags: story-identification, comics, manga, magic

It's about a girl who is a maid and I think she got reincarnated into a book of fairy tales involving princesses (there were princesses who were taking tests about fairy tales. Like "The Princess and the Pea" and how you felt had to feel the pea under the mattress). The MC had brown hair and green eyes and she's cunning. She has a crush on this man who had blonde hair and blue eyes. Everyone one the princesses is taking a test to be the next chosen one who get to marry the blonde haired dude. The MC is forced to do what the other princesses are doing even though she's a maid.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What are "princess things?"  When and where did you read this?

Comment: When I mean "princess things" they were princesses and they were taking test about fairytales. Like princess and the pea and how you felt had to feel the pea under the mattress. I read this 2 years ago and I don't know when I read this.

Comment: Is it possible that the candidate was not a maid, but a waiter for her family's restaurant?

Comment: She could be a waiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Princess Wars](https://anilist.co/manga/120642/Gongzhu-Zhanzheng/)*.

> War for a second chance at life!
> Han Moli died as she lived: working. When her soul then enters the world of the "Princess Game," she's **pitted against other players** for a chance at resurrection. But in order to win, she has to marry the prince! As the penniless **Princess Pea**, does she even stand a chance?

[image: Cover image]

The cover image shows the protagonist, with brown hair and green eyes, and the blonde haired prince.

She was an office worker, not a maid, and abruptly dies as a result of overwork. She's given a chance of a new life as the princess from *The Princess and the Pea* and must compete with other princesses from other fairy tales.

During the test to see if anyone could detect the pea under a mattress, one of the candidates cheats to remove all of the peas from the other mattresses. The protagonist confronts her over this but is unable to prove the other woman cheated. As a result, the protagonist is asked to serve as a maid instead of a princess.

[image: Work as a maid]